# Store data from a mysql database into a C++ variable using mysql connector

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

So I downloaded the c++/mysql connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/
Now I want to store data that I've retrieved from the database to a variable. This is as far as I've gotten.

```
string str;
/////////////////////////////////get data from database////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("awesome");

  stmt= con->createStatement();

      res = stmt->executeQuery(

"SELECT * FROM master where choice='Y'");

/////////////////////////////Store it somewhere/////////////////////////////// 
          str= res->getString("rfid");
```

Any and all help is welcomed

Comment: You have stored data in str variable. What is the question about then? Also posting full example source would be helpful.

Comment: Error I get    

>Unhandled exception at 0x75a54b32 in camera.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::InvalidArgumentException at memory location 0x0026e014..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not that easy to guess what is happening without rest of the code and database data, following code should help to at least get better understanding on what went wrong:

```
  try
  {
    while (res->next())
    {
          str= res->getString("rfid");
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception &e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I never thought to even do that even though it's right in the documentation. If I had more rep I'd up vote you.