# sql::InvalidArgumentException MySql C++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using VisualStudio 12 for develop one app. In that app i need do some mySql call's, i have that code:

```
sql::Statement *stmt = db->global->createStatement();
sql::ResultSet *res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `tbl_jobs` WHERE name = 'maintenance';");
Server->maintenance = (res->getString("data") == "on")? true : false;
```

The query is ok, work's well on Navicat, but on:

```
res->getString("data")
```

Ever throw's that error:

> Unhandled exception at ...: Microsoft C++ exception: sql::InvalidArgumentException at memory location ....

If i done sql::SQlException throw i get this log:

> ERROR: SQLException in ....
>   Function: main on line 33
>   ERROR: MySQL_ResultSet::getString: can't fetch because not on result set
>   (MySql error code: 1544116026, SqlState: MySQL_ResultSet::getString: can't fetch because not on result set)

I understan the sql::ResultSet don't have any data, but if i print res->rowsCount() say me are 1 row... I tryed with res->first(), but throws random error's.

¿Any ideas? :c

Comment: Can you use try/ catch. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004540/store-data-from-a-mysql-database-into-a-c-variable-using-mysql-connector

Comment: you need to tag this with mysql c++ connector?

Comment: @ ldgorman Added, @metalfightm i alredy use but return's "ERROR:  SQLException...."

Answer (score 2):

You must call next() or similar in order for your resultset to point to the nth result in the set

If your resultset is empty calling getString() will fail. check for a result before continuing. something like:

```
if(!res->next())
  return; //Handle Failiure
```

Do this before you try to operate on your results

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html) they are using a while loop alternatively.

Comment: Make another errror on inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all(),  in xutility, and i can't read any with debugger

Answer (score 1):

call `res->next()` before your first `getString(...)` function